# How to fix Open Redirect Fortify issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to resolve Fortify Open Redirect Issue? 
In the below code because of line number 2 & 4 I'm getting Open Redirect fortify Issue. How to resolve the below code kindly help.

```
_submitAccountPayment () {
        const poNumber = $(this.poNumberSelector).val();
        const paramPoNumber = poNumber ? `&poNumber=${encodeURIComponent(poNumber)}` : '';

        window.location.href = `${ACC.config.checkoutUpdatePaymentTypeUrl}?accountPayment=true${paramPoNumber}`;
    }
```